# Python Crash Course- project 'Alien Invasion' -Error

Tags: python

I started writing the code for the file name *alien_invasion.py* in the book python crash course, page number 228. I encountered the following error-
*NameError: name '*name*' is not defined*

This occurs when the final lines of the program in the file *alien_invasion.py* written within the *if* block is executed. That is

```
if _name_ == '_main_':
  ai. = AlienInvasion()
  ai.run_game()
```

Comment: it's **two** underscores ```if __name__ == "__main__":```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing '_' at the beginning and end. The code should look like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```